# Handles behavior in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab

Why does this not work? As you can see in the error report below, the field handles.check is not carried to the callback function.

```
function example2_4

N=500;
M=300;

handles.fig=figure('Units','Pixels',...
    'Position',[100 100 N M])

handles.axes=axes('Units','Pixels',...
    'Position',[25 25 N-200 M-50]);

handles.check=uicontrol('style','checkbox',...
    'string','Enable Axes Grid Lines',...
    'Position',[N-150,M/2-25 150 50],...
    'Callback',{@checkbox_callback,handles});

function checkbox_callback(gcf,event_data,handles)
handles
val=get(handles.check,'Value');
if val
    grid on;
else
    grid off;
end
```

Error report:

```
handles = 

     fig: 2
    axes: 331.0076

Reference to non-existent field 'check'.

Error in example2_4>checkbox_callback (line 19)
val=get(handles.check,'Value');

Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Yet, this one does work. This time the handles.check is carried to the callback function.

```
function example2_4

N=500;
M=300;

handles.fig=figure('Units','Pixels',...
    'Position',[100 100 N M]);

handles.axes=axes('Units','Pixels',...
    'Position',[25 25 N-200 M-50]);

handles.check=uicontrol('style','checkbox',...
    'string','Enable Axes Grid Lines',...
    'Position',[N-150,M/2-25 150 50]);

set(handles.check,'Callback',{@checkbox_callback,handles});


function checkbox_callback(gcf,event_data,handles)
handles
val=get(handles.check,'Value');
if val
    grid on;
else
    grid off;
end
```

Handles report:

```
handles = 

      fig: 3
     axes: 488.0044
    check: 489.0044
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a copy of `handles` is being passed into the callback.  So in

```
handles.check=uicontrol('style','checkbox',...
   'string','Enable Axes Grid Lines',...
   'Position',[N-150,M/2-25 150 50],...
   'Callback',{@checkbox_callback,handles});
```

`handles`, as being passed as an argument to the `checkbox_callback`, has only the `axes` and `fig` fields set, as the code is only in the process of creating the `check` field.

Whereas in

```
set(handles.check,'Callback',{@checkbox_callback,handles});
```

`handles` (or its copy) has the `fig`, `axes`, and `check` fields already set given the three previous statements.

**EDIT**

I always use GUIDE to create my GUIs and then rely on the `guidata` function to get and set fields within the `handles` structure.  In your example, you may have to do something similar either with `guidata` or with the `setappdata` and `getappdata` functions.  See [Share Data Amongst Callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html) for details.